# Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to display data from my json file but I have an error that I can't find a solution to, despite my research on stackoverflow.

i have this error: **Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed**

**json**

```
{
  "flags": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "mnemo": "KHM",
      "libelle": "Cambodge",
      "bigramme": "KH"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "mnemo": "KHM",
      "libelle": "France",
      "bigramme": "FR"
    },
]
}
```

**ts.file**

```
export class HomepageComponent implements OnInit {

  postArray: Ipost[] = [];

  constructor(private homeService: HomeService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAllNations();
  }

  getAllNations() {
    this.homeService.getAll().subscribe(result => {
      this.postArray = result;
      console.log(this.postArray);
    });
  }    
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="col-1 px-0" *ngFor="let post of postArray">
      <div *ngIf="post.id >= 13">
        <span>{{post.libelle}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**interface**

```
export interface Ipost {
  id:number,
  mnemo:string,
  libelle:string,
  bigramme:string
}
```

Comment: The error message is clear. The array is contained in the `flags` property of the `postArray` variable. Try: `*ngFor="let post of postArray?.flags"`. The safe navigation operator `?.` will check if the `postArray` variable is defined before accessing it's property `flag`.

Comment: **OR** based on your variable declaration, you need to initialize it with the `flags` property in the subscription: `this.postArray = result['flags']`. In this case, the template doesn't need any change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify postArray to `postArray.flags` in *ngFor.
because postArray refers to the Whole Json object which is not an array, but `postArray.flags` is the array you want to reach out to.

Initialise Ipost like below in ts file

```
postArray: Ipost[] = undefined;
```

and change template code like below

```
<ng-container *ngIf="postArray">
    <div class="col-1 px-0" *ngFor="let post of postArray?.flags">
          <div *ngIf="post.id >= 13">
            <span>{{post.libelle}}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
```

Comment: Property 'flags' does not exist on type 'Ipost[]'.